# unable to find anti forgery token in filterContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

I am referring the below link for implementing anti forgery in my web application.

[link](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/anti-forgery-request-recipes-for-asp-net-mvc-and-ajax)

```
$.ajaxAntiForgery({
    type: "POST",            
    url: "sampleapp",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {       }
});
```

The token is created as described in the document but in the codebehind it throws error in the below line.

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    private readonly ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute _validator;
    private readonly AcceptVerbsAttribute _verbs;
    protected BaseController (HttpVerbs verbs)
    {
        this._verbs = new AcceptVerbsAttribute(verbs);
        this._validator = new ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute();            
    }

    protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        string httpMethodOverride = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.GetHttpMethodOverride();
        if (this._verbs.Verbs.Contains(httpMethodOverride, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            this._validator.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class ValidateTokenAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public string VariableTokenKey = "__RequestVerificationToken";
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        try
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) { this.ValidateRequestHeader(filterContext.HttpContext.Request); }
            else { AntiForgery.Validate(); }
        }
        catch
        {
            InvalidRequest(filterContext, "103", "", "Token not found.");
        }
    }
    private void ValidateRequestHeader(HttpRequestBase request)
    {
        string cookieToken = string.Empty;
        string formToken = string.Empty;
        string tokenValue = request.Headers[this.VariableTokenKey]; // read the header key and validate the tokens.
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenValue))
        {
            var antiForgeryCookie = request.Cookies[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName];
            cookieToken = antiForgeryCookie != null ? antiForgeryCookie.Value : null;
        }
        AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, tokenValue); // this validates the request token.
    }
    private void InvalidRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext, string errorCode, string sMessage, string eMessage)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
            {
                Data = new { ErrorCode = errorCode, Message = eMessage },
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
        }
        else
        {
            ViewDataDictionary viewData = new ViewDataDictionary();
            viewData.Add("ShortMessage", "Access denied.");
            viewData.Add("Message", "Anti forgery token not found.");
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { MasterName = "", ViewName = "Error", ViewData = viewData };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you help me to understand what's wrong with the code I posted?

Comment: @Ammu - The code which you have posted is not enough for the reference to tell what went wrong. If you could let me know the entire class, then I could suggest at which part was compromised. I was able to build and run successfully based on your referral link.

Comment: I have updated whole code. Please let me know if it need any change.